# How to add linebreak in XML in Android Studio in strings.xml file

Tags: xml, android-studio

I am a newbie to android app dev. So lately I was making a about me app so how do I add a line break in the strings.xml file the code is on my GitHub page

-> Code link https://github.com/Tijil2111/About_Me/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

I tried adding /n but it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you define the string in `strings.xml` without new lines (in other words, get rid of the 'enters'). For example, in `strings.xml`,

```
<string name="Testing">Testing\nNew Line</string>
```

and set it to the `TextView` like this:

```
android:text="@string/Testing"
```

then you should see the following:

> Testing
>
> New Line

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this, you will have to make different text views for that.
I also check it, you can't do this.

Comment: It is certainly possible.